# Intents for Specific Web Sites - Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like my app receive intents if a specific link is shared from other apps. For example, the link is youtube. There are a couple links for youtube.

www.youtube.com/...

m.youtube.com/...

youtu.be/...

If any of these links are shared, either from youtube app, or chrome or some other app, I want my app to be on the share list. Otherwise I don't want it to be shown at the share list. I think I've seen some apps do this but I'm not sure how.

I added these codes to manifest file but on chrome every link can be shared to my app.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:host="m.youtube.com" android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:host="youtu.be"
          android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

I can handle the link with the code in the activity file, but I'm looking for another way to limit the links with the ones I specifically give.

I'm a newbee on Android so forgive me if this question sounds a little bit off.

Thank you,

Comment: I found out by the help of the answer by @CommonsWare, that Android Studio has App Links Assistant which adds necessary codes to the manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible. You cannot filter on a value in an extra (e.g., `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM`).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Is there any alternative way? Such as when you click on a youtube link, open my app?

Comment: @MeCe: That would be `ACTION_VIEW`, or `android.intent.action.VIEW` in terms of an `<action>` in the manifest. That will work, though [you need to add `android:scheme` attributes to your `<data>` elements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) and fix (or remove) your MIME types (as videos are not text).

Comment: Thank you, got it.